# Hello. How can I solve the error code "array subscript is not an integer"? I also have a couple of questions about arrays and switch/case arguments

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, switch-statement, case

I am getting "error: array subscript is not an integer" on lines 47, 48, 69, 70, 80 and 89. Basically every line I try to use the users input to select which "slot" of the array **foguetes[1000][2]** should be shown/deleted/created.

On those lines, I use **&variable**. I gather this is improper because of the errors, so what should I use insead?

I am thinking of doing the same thing for **case 6**, the user will select which slot of **foguetes[1000][2] should be used and then the deltaV will be calculated based on that data. How do I "pull" the values from two columns of a line of said array to put in place of **mCheia** and **mVazia** in this situation?

In **case 1** before I added the array and thus before the errors started happening, the first print and scan, Lines 36 and 37, were working fine, but the case ended there. Lines 39 trough 51 never worked/were printed. How can I fix that?

Thank you very much for reading and I apologize for any mistakes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
    
main () {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    int QntSubs, escolha, mF, eF, iF, ispMotor, qF, contagem, i, x; //mudarfoguete, excluir foguete, informaçao do foguete, massa do motor, qual foguete
    float foguetes[1000][2], dV, mCheia, mVazia, mMotor;
    
    do {
        printf ("\n1-Cadastrar os dados de um foguete"); // enter rocket values (dry and wet masses)
        printf ("\n2-Mudar os dados de um foguete já inserido"); // change rocket values (dry and wet masses)
        printf ("\n3-Excluir os dados de um foguete já inserido"); // delete rocket values (dry and wet masses)
        printf ("\n4-Listar os foguetes já cadastrados"); // list registered rockets (dry and wet masses)
        printf ("\n5-Incluir dados do motor substituto"); // enter substitute engine values (Total mass and Isp)
        printf ("\n6-Realizar cálculo de dV\n\n"); // calculate deltaV
    
        scanf ("%d", &escolha);
        fflush (stdin);
    
        switch(escolha) {
        case 1:
            printf ("\nQuantos foguetes serão cadastrados?: "); // how many rockets do you want to register?
            scanf ("%d", &x);
    
            for (contagem=x; contagem <= 0; contagem --) {
    
                printf ("\n\nMassa do estagio cheio(kg): "); // Wet Mass
                scanf ("%f", &mCheia);
    
                printf ("Massa do estagio vazio(kg): "); // dry Mass
                scanf ("%f", &mVazia);
    
                foguetes[&x][1] = mCheia;
                foguetes[&x][2] = mVazia;
            }
    
            break;
    
        case 2:
            printf ("\n\nMassa do estagio cheio(kg): "); // Wet Mass
            scanf ("%f", &mCheia);
            fflush (stdin);
    
            printf ("\nMassa do estagio vazio(kg): "); // Dry Mass
            scanf ("%f", &mVazia);
            fflush (stdin);
    
            printf ("\n\nQual foguete você deseja mudar?:"); // Which rocket shall be changed?
            scanf ("%d", &mF);
    
            foguetes[&mF][1] = &mCheia;
            foguetes[&mF][2] = &mVazia;
    
            break;
    
        case 3:
            printf ("\n\nQual é o número do foguete que você deseja excluir?: "); // Which rocket shall be deleted?
            scanf ("%f", &eF);
            fflush (stdin);
    
            foguetes[&eF][2] = 0;
    
            break;
    
        case 4:
            printf ("\n\nQual foguete você deseja ver as informações?: "); // Which rocket's values shall be showed?
            scanf ("%f", &iF);
    
            printf("foguete: %.1f\n", foguetes[&iF][2]);
    
            break;
    
        case 5:
            printf ("\n\nMassa total dos motores: "); // Engines total mass
            scanf ("%f", &mMotor);
            fflush (stdin);
    
            printf ("\n\nEficiência dos motores(Isp): "); // Engine efficiency (Isp)
            scanf ("%f", &ispMotor);
            fflush (stdin);
    
            break;
    
        case 6:
            printf ("\n\nPara qual foquete você quer calcular o dV? "); // Which rocket's deltaV shall be calculated?
            scanf ("%f", &qF);
            fflush (stdin);
    
            dV = (ispMotor * 9.80665 * log((mCheia + mMotor)/(mVazia + mMotor)));
    
            break;

        default:
            printf("\nOpção inválida. Por favor escolha um ação de 1-6 ou 0 para finalizar o programa.\n"); // Invalid option. Please choose an action between 1-6 or 0 to end the process
    
        }
    
    } while(escolha > 0);
    
    return(0);
    
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of `x` is an integer. `&x` is a pointer to the variable `x`. The index of an array must be an integer, so `foguetes[&x][1]` should be `foguetes[x][1]`.

You have similar errors for all your other arrays.

Comment: Every error was solved after I removed **&** but now I have "error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'float' from type 'float *' " on lines 69 and 70.

Comment: `foguetes[&mF][1] = &mCheia;` should be `foguetes[mF][1] = mCheia;` Why are you adding all these unnecessary `&`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove & from mCheia and mVazia. No erros now. I am still not able to go past line 37 inside of case 1 though. Do you have any suggestion for that problem?

Comment: `contagem <= 0` should be `contagem >= 0`. The condition in a `for` loop is for when it should execute the body, not when it should stop.